# How to update bash script whilst running or easily restart it?

Tags: java, bash, sh

I require a method to easily restart/replace bash scripts without manually stopping/starting the process over again.

Here's how my current script works:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
  echo "1"
  java -server -Xms2G -jar game.jar nogui
done
```

Basically, if the game stops, it will automatically restart however, the script is already loaded into memory so if I was to modify it, I would have to manually kill the script and start it up again in order for the changes to take effect. I'm running at least 200 instances of the game server itself so, it would not be intelligent to do this manually and kill, then start each script manually again.

When the game server stops, I wish for it to update the script, here is an example of what I may want to do:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
  echo "1"
  echo "2"
  java -server -Xms2G -jar game.jar nogui
done
```

However, I'd need to physically stop the script and start it again myself in order for it to add the new 'echo "2"', I need an easier way to replace the running script.

The script itself will download the updated script when the game stops (so it will automatically start again.

How can I make the script unload itself from memory, and use the new script?

If I cannot do this, is there any alternative method you can suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the following file `myscript.sh`.  It reloads itself into memory every time that the game stops:

```
#!/bin/sh
java -server -Xms2G -jar game.jar nogui
exec /path/to/myscript.sh
```

Comment: Managed to do it via:

**1.sh:**

    #!/bin/sh
    while true
    do
    
    ./2.sh
    
    done;

**2.sh:**

    echo "1"

I could then modify 2.sh and 1.sh would re-load into memory.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative method is to use a process supervision tool such as [runit](http://smarden.org/runit/), [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html), [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/), [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/), [systemd](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/), etc.

For any of these, you would write only the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec java -server -Xms2G -jar game.jar nogui
```

...and the supervision tool would be responsible for restarting the server on exit, rereading the script (and thus responding to updates) each time it needs to be run.

These tools give you far more features than just reliable restarts -- they typically also manage logging, staged shutdown (ie. TERM + timeout + KILL), custom cleanup commands, signal hooks, etc.

See also the [ProcessManagement page on the freenode #bash wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement).

---

If you can't use a process management system (and you really, really should!), you can have the script exec itself. That is to say:

```
#!/bin/sh
# ...do stuff here...
exec "$0" "$@" # and restart
```

Note that this is unreliable for various reasons related to [BashFAQ #28](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028).

Comment: @DogeCode, the `exec "$0" "$@"` above is pretty much the only thing your other question requires an an answer. Caveat that it's more reliable if using `"${BASH_SOURCE:-$0}"` instead of `$0`, to use the more accurate `BASH_SOURCE` variable if available (meaning, if the shell in use is bash). See [BashFAQ #28](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028) about limitations in `$0`. BTW, if you hadn't deleted your other question, we could be continuing discussion in its comments, and potentially re-opening it if it were to be edited into an unambiguously distinct question.